# How can script from pg_get_functiondef() be used to create stored procedures in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, psql, pgadmin

Using the following code, the text file "myprocedures" containing the stored procedures is created.

Is there anyway without alteration to apply this file to an existing database on another machine? Or how best to use this file to generate the procedures on another database? (i.e., how can it be used directly in PgAdmin or psql?).

My problem is there are symbols (like "+" and "\r" generated in the script that are not recognized with

```
"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\bin\psql.exe" -h xxx.xxx.x.xxx -p 5432 -U postgres -d chaos -1 -v ON_ERROR_STOP -f C:/temp/myprocedures
```

TIA

PostgreSQL version 9.3

Windows 7 Ultimate

PgAdmin III

```
File: dump_stored_procedures.sql

SELECT pg_get_functiondef(f.oid)
FROM pg_catalog.pg_proc f
INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON (f.pronamespace = n.oid)
WHERE n.nspname = 'public';

--------------------------------------------------------

File: dump_procedures.bat

setlocal
set PGPASSWORD=password
"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\bin\psql.exe" -h localhost -U postgres 
-d  chaos -f C:/temp/dump_stored_procedures.sql >> C:/temp/myprocedures
pause
endlocal
```

Edit #1: Here is an example of the first few procedure definitions in myprocedures. Note the unnecessary addition of "pg_get_function", the "---", and all the "+" and "\r":

```
    pg_get_functiondef                                                                                                                                                                                
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.empty(text)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  +
  RETURNS boolean                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               +
  LANGUAGE sql                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  +
  IMMUTABLE                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     +
 AS $function$ SELECT $1 ~ '^[[:space:]]*$'; $function$                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         +

 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.f_getallprogressnotes(groupid character varying)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             +
  RETURNS SETOF view_progressnote                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               +
  LANGUAGE sql                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  +
 AS $function$ \r                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               +
 \r                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             +
  select \r                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     +
         et.eid, et.groupid, et.cpatient, et.tencounter, et.checkout, et.notseen,  \r                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           +
         et.complexity,  p.note, r.appointmentmetadata, r.rtn\r                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 +
  from \r                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       +
         encountertimes et \r                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   +
  left outer join \r                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            +
         progressnote p \r                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      +
  on \r                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         +
         (et.eid = p.eid)\r                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     +
  left outer join \r                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            +
         returntooffice r \r                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    +
  on \r                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         +
         (et.eid = r.eid) \r                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    +
  where\r                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       +
         et.groupid =$1 \r                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      +
 order by et.tencounter desc     \r                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             +
 \r                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             +
 $function$                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     +

 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.f_getallvitalsigns(groupid character varying)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                +
  RETURNS SETOF vitalsigns                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      +
  LANGUAGE sql                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  +
 AS $function$ \r                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               +
 select v.*\r                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   +
   from \r                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      +
         vitalsigns v \r                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        +
   right join ( \r                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              +
         select \r                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              +
                 eid, tencounter \r                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             +
         from \r                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                +
                 encountertimes\r                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               +
         where\r                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                +
                 groupid = $1\r                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 +
         order by\r                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             +
                 tencounter asc\r                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               +
         ) j\r                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  +
 on (v.eid = j.eid)                              \r                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             +
   $function$
```

etc., etc., etc., ....

Comment: Could you post error message (and line which it causes) mentioned in _My problem is there are symbols (like "+" and "\r" generated in the script that are not recognized_ ?

Comment: @RadekPostołowicz Sure thing. First error is:    psql:C:/temp/myprocedures:944  ERROR:  syntax error at or near "pg_get_functiondef"
   LINE 1: pg_get_functiondef.  Examination of the  myprocedures file shows that it starts with "pg_get_functiondef"  nicely centered at the top of the file.  Ideas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pg_get_functiondef` at the top of the file is the column header of the database resultset you've asked `psql` to output. You can suppress it by using the `--tuples-only` argument to `psql`.

The `\r`s in the output are a representation of a "carriage return" - one half of the "CR LF" convention used by DOS/Windows programs for line breaks, where a Unix/Linux system would use only "LF". I've not been able to reproduce them being there, but a simple if not 100% safe solution would be to replace them away. You can also add a semicolon at the same time:

```
SELECT replace(pg_get_functiondef(f.oid), '\r', '') || ';'
...
```

Another option to investigate is using `pg_dump` in "custom format" mode (`-Fc`), and then using `pg_restore` to selectively restore (or generate SQL for) the desired functions. See [the docs for `pg_restore`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-pgrestore.html).

Comment: I have not tried loading it yet, but it appears the --tuples-only suppresses all the unnecessary stuff--including the "+" and "\r". Thanks.

Comment: I am wrong. the "\r" are retained within the tuples. Additionally the output script does NOT contain the terminal semicolon, ";" needed to run the script in PgAdmin. I guess a wordprocessor can be used to fix this. Any other ideas?

Comment: Well, the missing semicolon is easy - concatenate it onto your query - and I already suggested something for the \r. See my edit.

Comment: Got this. call psql with -A --tuples-only will suppress the "\r" from the tuples as well. Still need to add the terminating semicolon, however.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @IMSoP for pointing me in the right direction. The following are working scripts I used with psql. No wordprocessor editing is needed!

```
--------------------------------------------------------
File:  dump_stored_prodecures.sql

SELECT pg_get_functiondef(f.oid)||';'
FROM pg_catalog.pg_proc f
INNER JOIN pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON (f.pronamespace = n.oid)
WHERE n.nspname = 'public';

--------------------------------------------------------
File:  dump_procedures.bat

setlocal
del C:\temp\myprocedures
set PGPASSWORD=***********
"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\bin\psql.exe" -h localhost  -At -U postgres -d chaos -f C:/temp/dump_stored_procedures.sql >> C:/temp/myprocedures
pause
endlocal

----------------------------------------------------------
File:  load_procedures.bat

setlocal
del C:\temp\Errors.txt
set PGPASSWORD=*********
"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.3\bin\psql.exe" -1 -v ON_ERROR_STOP -h xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -p 5432 -U postgres -d chaos  -f C:/temp/myprocedures  2>> C:/temp/Errors.txt
notepad C:/temp/Errors.txt
endlocal
```

Useage:
     In the DOS command prompt, run dump_procedures.bat to create the text file "myprocedures".  Then run load_procedures.bat to modify the PostgreSQL databae. Be sure to read the Errors.txt file!

Hope this helps somebody.